# loop ifelse for multiple data frames

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I want to create a loop to repeat code lines in a list of datasets.
Each dataset looks like:

```
gwas_1 
   ID   p
    1   0.0000005
    2   0.0123474
    ... 
gwas_2 
   ID   p
    1   0.0000055
    2   0.5854587
    ...
```

So I would like to create a new column and check frequencies in a new column in each dataset.I did it before like this

```
  data=gwas_1
  data$p_threshold <- ifelse(data$p<0.001, 1, 0)
  table (data$p_threshold)
  data=gwas_2
  data$p_threshold <- ifelse(data$p<0.001, 1, 0)
  table (data$p_threshold)
```

but realised that it might not very efficient. Could you please help me to create a loop as my loop doesn't work ("Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"):

```
 list=c("gwas_1, gwas_2, gwas_3")
 for (db in list){
 db$p_threshold <- ifelse(db$p<0.001, 1, 0)
 table (db$p_threshold)
 }
```

Comment: simply use `+(data$p<0.001)` instead of `ifelse(data$p<0.001, 1, 0)` its much faster

Comment: Just a couple of pointers:

your vector ```list=c("gwas_1, gwas_2, gwas_3")``` has just one elemnt which is the character string ```"gwas_1, gwas_2, gwas_3"```, remove the quotes ```" . "``` to have the data frames in ```list```.


Try not to use ```list``` as a variable name since it is reserved function name in R.

And finally use the ```apply``` functions when you can instead of ```for``` loops

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

set up data:

```
set.seed(1337)
tmp <- data.frame(p = runif(100)*.007)
l1  <- list(gwas_1 = tmp, gwas_2 = tmp, gwas_3 = tmp)
```

code:

```
lapply(l1, function(x) table(+(x[["p"]]<0.001)))
```

result:

```
#$gwas_1
#
# 0  1 
#88 12 
#
#$gwas_2
#
# 0  1 
#88 12 
#
#$gwas_3
#
# 0  1 
#88 12
```

---

- put all your data.frames into a list (like `l1`)
- use `lapply`

---

already: ~ 15 times faster than `ifelse`

```
#> set.seed(1337)
#> tmp<-data.frame(p = runif(99999999)*.007)
#> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(+(tmp[["p"]]<0.001) , ifelse(tmp[["p"]]<0.001, 1, 0), times = 4)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                             expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#            +(tmp[["p"]] < 0.001)  463.054  527.4309 1779.396 1440.110 3031.362 3774.312     4  a 
# ifelse(tmp[["p"]] < 0.001, 1, 0) 7071.470 7140.4354 8021.247 7887.672 8902.058 9238.173     4   b
```